# Can I Close a FragmentContainerView from Inside a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is my first time using Fragments and I'm rather new to Android. I'm using Fragments to manage a settings menu for my app.

I have a MainActivity with a FragmentContainerView, the XML is like so:

```
 <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_fragment_container"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

In the MainActivity.java File I have a method assigned to a button to make the FragmentContainerView visible, like so:

```
private void showFragments(FragmentContainerView fragmentContainerView) {

    fragmentContainerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // There is more to this method, but I don't think it is necessary for this example
}
```

I'm able to navigate all around the settings menu: inflate fragments, replace fragments, update Shared Preferences, use Browser Intent, etc.  - everything I need to do for a settings menu.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to closeout the Settings Menu (close the FragmentContainerView in the MainActivity) after a selection has been made (and thus return to the game). I can create a "close" button in every fragment - but I can't figure out a method to close (setVisibility to GONE) the MainActivity's FragmentContainerView.

***Once I'm in a Fragment - is it even possible to access the FragmentContainerView the fragment resides inside of?*** I've tried a number of ways to access it and set the visibility to GONE, but I just get a crash.

Inside a fragment:

```
FragmentContainerView mainActivityFragmentContainer = (FragmentContainerView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_fragment_container);


public void closeFragment(FragmentContainerView mainActivityFragmentContainer) {
     
        mainActivityFragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
       // This causes a crash, the error log states:
       // NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

}
```

I know a workaround where I don't have the fragmentContainerView fill up the entire screen and leave space for an external close button - but this solution seems inefficient.Any advice would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it,

1- Create a public function in your `MainActivity` that closes the fragment container:

```
public void closeFragment() {
    fragmentContainerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

2- Call that function from your fragment when you need it:

```
// getActivity() will return the activity linked to that fragment so this fragment should be linked MainActivity
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
acitvity.closeFragment();
```

Comment: THANKS!!!! Perfect answer. I was fooling around on my own and I was soooo close to coming up with that solution. I pivoted to another solution too - using the "addOnBackStackChangedListener" and when the count reach 0 I dismissed the fragment. However this solution is much simpler! Thanks!